# Recommended books/links for Fourier Transform beginners?

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

I am a student taking engineering course and wish to learn more about Fourier Transforms. It seems very useful. Would highly appreciate it if anyone could advise me where to start.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention what kind of engineering course you are taking, since there are books for various engineering specialties, e.g. http://books.google.com/books?id=WoRZyjM6iREC

Comment: I am taking electrical engineering course. I didn't specify because I thought Fourier could be applied on various areas. I even saw a book of Fourier Transform for Finance. =O

Comment: Well, that's because of 1. a lot of things in applications can be couched in terms of Fourier transforms, and 2. there exists a speedy algorithm called the "fast Fourier transform" (FFT), and if you have a sleek-looking hammer, you tend to start looking for nails...

Answer (score 2):

I first learned Fourier techniques from [Bracewell's *The Fourier Transform and Its Applications*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073039381), but I'm digging the non-conventional treatment in [Meikle's *A New Twist to Fourier Transforms*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3527404414).

Comment: wao..the first book is a long one. Is this the best for beginners?

Comment: @learn: Well, there is the assumption that your calculus is solid... and you didn't mention your mathematical background.

Comment: M.: I took calculus module last semester in my uni. that was the first time I learn about line integral, surface integral etc. so I dare not to say I am solid in those... but for basic differentiation and integration I am sure I can handle them.

Comment: I suppose that ought to be okay. In any event, if you're unclear about something, that's what teachers and this site are for...

Comment: I read some good reviews of Bracewell's book, but I can now say after reading some of it that it is much worse than I had anticipated. It is long and full of poorly explained material.  It makes many assumptions about the reader's knowledge, and does a poor job of explaining many difficult to grasp concepts.  In addition, the flow and structure of the book is quite poor as well.  Certainly not a book for anyone wishing to fully understand the Fourier transform in a clear, concise manner in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

For a general engineering perspective, Erwin Kreyszig's  book "[Advanced Engineering Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470458364)" would have some chapters on Fourier and other integral transforms.

For a more mathematical approach, but still with applications in mind, Sneddon's book [Fourier Transforms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486685225) is recommended. It has a lot of physics applications.

The book of Taub and Schilling on [Principles of Communication Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070629552) is very good from an electrical engineering point of view. I particularly liked this last book.

Answer (score 1):

This link is really, really good!

Fourier Transform in one day
http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/dft-a-pied/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an interest in engineering optics or linear systems, try [Gaskill's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471292885).  It's good to start from.

[David Kammler's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521709792) is also a a good introduction.  The first part explains the connections between Fourier Series, Fourier Transform, DTFT, DFT very clearly which other books often gloss over.